# Value from hidden field is not being passed to the EF context model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have a few values that I've put in some hidden fields of a form using Razor. When I submit the form, it does not pass the validation that Entity Framework created in the `context.tt` model of a certain field. When I submit, there is an error thrown saying that the field cannot be null. This led me to believe that the value was null in the HTML. When I checked the source this is what i found:

```html
<input Value="1" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PoolType must be a number." id="PoolType" name="PoolType" type="hidden" value="" />
<input Value="Not Complete" id="LoanStatus" name="LoanStatus" type="hidden" value="" />
<input Value="2012-12-12 09:26.39" data-val="true" data-val-required="The DateStamp field is required." id="DateStamp" name="DateStamp" type="hidden" value="" />
```

I'm wondering why the `input` with id `LoanStatus` has a value set but it is throwing an error saying that it cannot be null. The exception thrown is:

> System.Data.ConstraintException This property cannot be set to a null value.

To set the value in the HTML, I set it in the controller using the ViewBag, `ViewBag.LoanStatus = "Not Complete";`. Then in the cshtml file `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LoanStatus, new { @Value = ViewBag.LoanStatus })`

Is there something I am missing, I am new to MVC and Entity Framework.

**EDIT - Additional Code**
More hidden elements

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID, new{ @Value = ViewBag.ID })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Reason, new{ @Value = ViewBag.Reason })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PoolType, new{ @Value = ViewBag.PoolType })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LoanStatus, new{ @Value = ViewBag.LoanStatus })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DateStamp, new{ @Value = ViewBag.DateTime })
```

And the html that is produced

```
<input Value="55" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input Value="1" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Reason must be a number." id="Reason" name="Reason" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input Value="1" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PoolType must be a number." id="PoolType" name="PoolType" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input Value="Not Complete" id="LoanStatus" name="LoanStatus" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input Value="2012-12-12 10:00.46" data-val="true" data-val-required="The DateStamp field is required." id="DateStamp" name="DateStamp" type="hidden" value="" />
```

**EDIT Code without Html helper**
Line from .cshtml file
`<input type="hidden" name="LoanStatus" id="LoanStatus" data-val="true" value="@ViewBag.LoanStatus" />`

Line from html source
`<input type="hidden" name="LoanStatus" id="LoanStatus" data-val="true" value="Not Complete" />`

Comment: Can you show the action method code?

Comment: Why does that line have "Value" in it twice?

Comment: @vtortola do you mean the method that does the validation in the context.tt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `@Html.HiddenFor` the value for the input is read from your model object. You try to overwrite it by specifying a value for the `Value` attribute. I guess this won't work and as you see, you get empty value attributes.

To solve your problem, don't use the viewbag but pass a model object with the values set to your view like this:

**Controller:**

```
return View(new YourModel { LoanStatus = "Not Complete" });
```

**View:**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LoanStatus)
```

Comment: Will this work when I am in the view to create a new record for the model?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. The views responsibility is just to render some HTML. The data is provided by the controller action.

Comment: What i meant is that I did not have a full model to pass and the view was supposed to gather data to created the model record. But when I re-read what you were doing and you are creating a new model with certain values filled in then passing it to the view. This worked, thank you.

Comment: Typically your controllers action method is responsible to generate the model data you need to display your view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Html helper here, why not try just making the line manually as follows:

`<input type="hidden" name="LoanStatus" value="@ViewBag.LoanStatus"/>`

I still don't know why each of your lines has the value set in 2 places. Could you post more code?

EDIT: I think that the lowercase value is being passed back into your controller. Try using @value (lowercase v) instead and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I only specify Value(with capital V). value is added when the HTML is produced and sent to the client

Comment: It would seem to me, then, that the value (lowercase v) is the one that's being passed back, and that's empty.

Comment: I tried using `@value` as apposed to `@Value` and that did not work either. value was not set in the html

Comment: In that case, try what I wrote above with manually making the line instead of relying on the HTML helper.

Comment: I also tried your idea of not using the Html helper. The value was set in the html but it still threw the same error about the value being null

Comment: What type is that LoanStatus field? Is it a string or an enum? Also, are you sure you're putting those fields inside of the form tag?

Comment: LoanStatus is a string and it is inside the form tag.

Comment: Try to put that value into the ViewData dictionary instead of the ViewBag: http://brendan.enrick.com/post/difference-between-viewbag-and-viewdata-in-mvc-3.aspx